# Need to turn off ModPagespeed

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-pagespeed, google-pagespeed

I've been trying to turn off the ModPagespeed module for this site : 
http://www.mundo-satelital.com.ar
, firstly through .htaccess

```
<IfModule pagespeed_module>
    ModPagespeed off
</IfModule>
```

And I also tried `ModPagespeedDisallow *` in place of `ModPagespeed off` but no effect.

When I don't include the IfModule and just have the `ModPagespeed off` I get a server error, does that mean that ModPagespeed isn't being detected?

Using this address however does turn off ModPagespeed :

http://www.mundo-satelital.com.ar/?ModPagespeed=off

However I don't want to have to use this all the time, I guess there's probably a URL rewrite that could hide this but seems like there should be a simpler way.

I tried logging into the Virtual Admin and using the file explorer to the etc/ folder but there is only a php.ini file there and no httpd.conf. If there's a way to change it from the VirtualAdmin UI I'd like to try that too, I had a look at the 'Directives' section but there's no mention of ModPageSpeed.

I'd like to know do I need to contact the hosting company to get this changed? Ideally I'd like to change in in .htaccess file but seems to get ignored. Am I overlooking something simple here? Modpagespeed is only turned on or off in server settings, right, it's not something like a script in the page source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you install mod_pagespeed? It sounds like it is installed on a different server, otherwise the `ModPagespeed off` command would work. Or are you using PageSpeed Service? If so, you would have to un-CNAME.

Comment: I was working on a job where I only had access to the public html folder. For anyone else who sees this I didn't figure out how to fix it, but the server owner manager to turn it off, so I would guess this is the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8940154/114308

Hope this helps, when you want in just one URL in specific!

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, I'd rather not use the url version. It's no longer a problem for me, the server owner changed his configuration and I'd recommend anyone with the same problem to try the same.